# Redshift data loading with Python script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I have to load millions of records into redshift DB (this is a must), what would be the most efficient/fast way of doing this? Right now I'm creating a dictionary in which I'm storing *chunks* of rows, that are casted to strings, so that I can place them within a query-string and then, using Pandas such as:

```py
with psycopg2.connect(prs.rs_conection_params_psycopg2) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as c:
        c.execute(query_create_empty_main_table)

        for chunk in df_chunks.keys():

            query_to_insert_new_data = """
                INSERT INTO {}
                {}
                VALUES
                {};
                """.format(table_name, column_names, df_chunks[chunk])

            c.execute(q_inserting_new_data)

        conn.commit()
```

The table is created from scratch every time, since it has *dynamic* information.

Would be appropriated to use Pyspark (if possible) or Parallel module? in that case, how could it be done? Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, however batching up inserts in not a good one!

My favorites:

- Option 1 - Python -> S3 CSV -> Redshift using Redshift COPY command
- Option 2 - Python -> S3 PARQUET -> Redshift using Redshift Spectrum

Your choice will depend upon the use case that you have in mind.